# Using PHP script to save an image file in localhost - wont work

Tags: javascript, php, html, apache, webstorm

All,

I have followed the link below to get PHP working on my MacBook Pro (OS 10.12.6).  I even get the phpinfo to appear when I use 
http://localhost/~USERNAME/phpinfo.php.  ~USERNAME is replaced with my real username.

However when I create a new project in WebStorm (2016.3.1) and use the HTML and PHP code below....I run into problems.  My goal is to have an upload input button so that a user can upload an image into my localhost staging folder.  However, when run my index.html in WebStorm the upload.php file is downloaded into my download folders.  And my chosen file in the input element never makes it into the staging folder.

FYI, I have modified my local php.ini to include the entries below.  I then restarted apache2 (via sudo apachectl restart).

Would you guys happen to know what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks for any help.

LINK to setup PHP on MAC

https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/setup-local-web-server-apache-php-
   osx-yosemite.html

```
HTML
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

PHP

```
 <?php

   $uploaddir = 'staging/';
   $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);

 ?>

   PHP.INI

   file_uploads = on
   post_max_size = 40M
   upload_max_filesize = 40M
   post_max_size = 40M
   max_execution_time : 6000
   max_input_time : 6000
   memory_limit : 128M
```

Comment: You probably have PHP's error reporting turned off. Even so, you probably would have found the answer that @RiggsFolly gave you if you looked at Apaches error log (next time! ) :)

Comment: Do you have a suggestion to look at logs.  I looked in the /var/log/apache2 and renamed the error_log and access_log.  However a new error_log file was not created after I tried running my site.

Comment: Add these two lines to the FIRST PHP file your project calls (index.php, etc). It doesn't have to be present in every file, just called a single time before the rest of your code executes: `ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`  that will just put the errors on your screen which is even easier for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The `name` attribute in the input must match the name used in the PHP script

```
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So amend the PHP script like this

```
<?php

    $uploaddir = 'staging/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
    //                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
    //                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^

?>
```

Comment: RiggsFolly, I copied your suggested code verbatim.  But my problem still occurs.  I will look into how to look at error codes....as Lucas Krupinski mentions.